# lua nginx ssl certificate setup

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, lua

I use [resty.http module](https://github.com/pintsized/lua-resty-http). But the data is used. For usual http or https without verification all works.

```
local http = require("resty.http").new()
local res, err = http:request_uri(url, {
    method = method,
    headers = headers,
    body = body,
    ssl_verify = false
})
```

But if I do not use `ssl_verify` it wouldn't work with the error:

> lua ssl certificate verify error: (20: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate),

I found using Google that `lua_ssl_trusted_certificate` can help. But I don't know how it can help. I have tested such command: `lua_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/GlobalSign_Root_CA.pem;` but it did not help to me.

How to verify https in a proper way?

Comment: The certificates are generally `.crt` files

Comment: @hjpotter92, lua_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt; gives the same incorrect behaviour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your nginx.conf you need to configure

```
lua_ssl_verify_depth 2;
lua_ssl_trusted_certificate /pathto-ca-certs.pem;
```

In my case my server calls out to only one external HTTPS endpoint. So I exported the certificate with the full chain (via borwser ceritificate export in Firefox) and imported into a PEM file. This is the .pem file that I supplied above.

I use lua-resty-http to make the calls to https and it works fine. You can use tools like wireshark/fiddler to monitor the outgoing connections to see if the requests are being made the way you want.